# Put a function of x as the x tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have two numpy arrays `x` and `y`, and I would like to plot a simple curve of `y` as a function of `x`. At the `y` axis, I would like to put (as labels) the values of `y`, but at the `x` axis I would like to put as labels some function of the values there.

For example, if `x=array([1, 2, 4, 8, 16])` and `y=array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1])`, I would like to assign labels to the xticks which will be the result of the following string formatting:

```
lambda x_val: "$2^{{+{:.0f}}}$".format(log2(x_val))
```

but I am interested in a general solution.

Comment: Please ping me if you disagree with the duplicate vote.

Comment: @tcaswell - no, I agree, thanks...

Comment: Great.  The one-vote close-as-duplicate power is very useful but a tad more power than I really want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter`. Shamelessly copying and adapting the [custom ticker](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html) example, something like this could work:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
import numpy as np

rc('text', usetex=True)

formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda x_val, tick_pos: "$2^{{+{:.0f}}}$".format(np.log2(x_val)))

x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 8, 16])
y = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

which results in

[image]

Note that the first label is bad; there'll be a division by zero warning issued when you run the code. That is because matplotlib scales the axis between 0 and 16, and puts a tick mark at 0 (which is then passed to the formatter). You could turn off that tick mark, or scale the x-axis differently to avoid that.

Comment: I'm not sure - what should be wrong with the 1 in my `x` array?

Comment: @Bach you're correct, it's not the input data. It's the automatic scaling of the x-axis by matplotlib that causes it. I've updated my answer according to that.

Answer (score 0):

For the case you have given:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 8, 16]) 
y = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1])

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(["$2^{{+{:.0f}}}$".format(np.log2(x_val)) for x_val in x])

plt.show()
```

[image]

For a more general solution you will want to specify the x_values at which you want the ticks as
`x` will in general have many more points than you want ticks. Either specify it manually or you can call `ax.get_xticklabels()` to get `matplotlib` to return the automated tick points.

For the most general method in which you simply tell matplotlib how you want the ticks formatted then see the Formatters section of [Jake Vanderplas tutorial](http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/vanderplas/Astr599/notebooks/12_AdvancedMatplotlib) or the [example in the docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html).

Comment: Using `set_*ticklabels` is in general dangerous because it de-couples the labels from the data coordinates (the only reasonable use is putting text labels on a bar chart where the x-units are nonsense anyway).