# How to format heatmap annotation floats to only show the decimal component

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, string-formatting, plot-annotations

I have floats and I'm interested in just the decimal places of them because the integer part is not important (and always will be the same in my problem).

I have to use string formatting because the number will be displayed on seaborn plots.
I'm using
`'0.2f'`
to display just two decimal, however I don't know how to remove the integer part.

Example:

I want to show
`.25` instead of `0.25`

Details:

**The implementation must work to format the values in [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)**:

```
sns.heatmap(table, annot = True, fmt = '.2f')
```

but I want to display just the decimals as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As per [Why doesn't f-string formatting work for Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58602185/7758804), an f-string can be used in a list-comprehension with `.apply`, to format all of the columns in the dataframe, which can then be passed to `annot=`, with `fmt=''`.

  - Each value is formatted with `f'{v:.2f}'[-3:]` where `.2f` rounds to two decimal places, and `[-3:]` slices the last three characters (e.g. `.xx`).
  - A typical [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) solution tries to avoid this usage of `.apply`, but given the size of a dataframe passed to `sns.heatmap`, this will not impact performance.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np  # for random data

# sample data
np.random.seed(20231118)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(6, 6)))

# create a new f-string formatted dataframe; these will be str dtype
annot = df.apply(lambda col: [f'{v:.2f}'[-3:] for v in col], axis=0)

# plot with annotations
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df, fmt='', annot=annot, cbar=False)
```

[image]

#### `df`

```
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  0.321406  0.647402  0.173481  0.885630  0.206138  0.584212
1  0.617528  0.782675  0.071267  0.858961  0.689791  0.093260
2  0.161312  0.069866  0.047737  0.804141  0.523107  0.635975
3  0.508007  0.890942  0.435791  0.281811  0.560090  0.384583
4  0.264682  0.501962  0.492275  0.143144  0.629373  0.445461
5  0.883968  0.207125  0.946935  0.222533  0.001788  0.622386
```

#### `annot`

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5
0  .32  .65  .17  .89  .21  .58
1  .62  .78  .07  .86  .69  .09
2  .16  .07  .05  .80  .52  .64
3  .51  .89  .44  .28  .56  .38
4  .26  .50  .49  .14  .63  .45
5  .88  .21  .95  .22  .00  .62
```

Comment: Don't know why the DV here since this is the only answer that works in sns.heatmap as requested.

Answer (score -1):

The following code extracts the 2 decimal points from a given floating point number.

```
float_number = 28.31
formatted_number = "{:.2f}".format(float_number).split('.')[1]
```

You can pass the above to a [formatter as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055060/put-a-function-of-x-as-the-x-tick-labels) and get the plotting done per your requirement.

Comment: This does not work to annotate the values in sns.heatmap, as requested

Answer (score -2):

You can try `nb -= int(nb)` or `decimalPart = nb - int(nb)` to make the number be only the decimal part.

Comment: It does not solve the formatting problem. The problem is not how to get the decimal  part, but how to format it